# Поместить title элемента в этот элемент

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно прописать код.

```
var size = $('.swatch-anchor').attr('title');
$('.swatch-anchor').text(size);
```

Проблема этого кода в том, что имея несколько элементов .swatch-anchor, title прописывается одинаковый. Как переписать код, чтобы title брался из конкретного элемента и в него же помещался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/bEL39/1/)

```
$('.swatch-anchor').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title')
    $(this).text(title);
});
```

Comment: Благодарю :)